# Why does my function not work when I do direct multiplication for variables

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
c = c - learning_rate \* ((10*c) + (8*d) - 34)
d = d - learning_rate \* ((8*c) + (10*d) - 38)
c_out\[i\] = c
d_out\[i\] = d
f3_out\[i\] = ((c + (2*d) -7)\*\*2) + (((2*c) + d - 5)\*\*2)
```

```
gradientC = (10 * c) + (8 * d) - 34
gradientD = (8 * c) + (10 * d) - 38
c = c - learning_rate * gradientC
d = d - learning_rate * gradientD
c_out[i] = c
d_out[i] = d
f3_out[i] = ((c + (2*d) -7)**2) + (((2*c) + d - 5))**2
```

I have to perform gradient descent on the following function (c + (2*d) -7)**2) + (((2*c) + d - 5))**2 but when I do so using the method in the first code block I don't get the desired output. It's only when I use a variable to represent the the gradients of D and C respectively that I get the correct answer. Just want to know what's causing this error so that I can learn.

Comment: In your first example, the calculation of `d` is using the *new* value of `c`, not the original one.  In the second example, both gradients are computed using the original values.